# Silverlight Textblock inside Listbox causes it to expand instead of wrapping the text

Tags: silverlight, listbox, grid, word-wrap, textblock

I have something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And the problem I'm having is that the TextBlock will expand the Grid column (and the Listbox) when the text is too long, instead of wrapping it as expected. Maybe I don't understand the star-sizing concept of Grids completely, but the way I see it, since the column width is set to "1*" which means "the remaining space available", the Textblock should NOT try to expand beyond this width, and should wrap the text instead.

So how can I fix this problem? By the way, I need the Grid (or some other container) because there will be other components besides the Textblock. Also the ItemContainerStyle section is there so that the Listbox element occupies the whole space.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` to your ListBox.

Comment: It didn't work. I get the same behavior (i.e. the content extended instead of being wrapped) but without scrollbars.

Comment: Can you post your full XAML code? If your ListBox is resizing, the text should wrap using your dataTemplate and the HorizontalScroll disabled. Maybe your listbox is inside a stackPanel or something that do not alow it to resize?

Comment: You know what? This actually *works*! I re-read your answer and I realized I was doing something else than what you suggested. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

you don't need column definitions if it will be just one, try with the following:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}"> 
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"> 
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter> 
        </Style> 
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate> 
            <Grid> 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/> 
            </Grid> 
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I need column definitions because there will be other components on the grid. I omitted them to simplify the example. Anyway I don't see how your example is different than mine, since by default columns are "*".

Comment: Good point. Alright, so forget everything I said about needing other components. And no, removing the column definitions doesn't work and produces exactly the same result.